Multi-tab state persistence in webapp
Having done this for awhile, I’d love a quick sanity check: in a web app using the History Web API is there any way to replicate state persistence across multiple primary nav tabs like you might expect in a native application? The only reasonable approach I can imagine uses iFrames with separate isolated experiences and manually triggering history events within each. But the browser back button would remain blissfully unaware of anything besides navigation in the parent wrapper between the 4-5 tabs.

Why are you using History API? I can't imagine you need iframes for this. What state are you losing? Are you really using react and ember?

Any sample code please?

If you are using Ember then you can persist state using the controller or component.js. Alternatively you can use a service to persist state. No need for iframes.
